# How can I make an SQS queue stop accepting new messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm working on a program that needs to accept queued requests, and I'd like to use SQS as my queue. My application doesn't care about message order, but it *does* need the ability to "close" a queue to accepting new events while draining the remaining messages.

For example, imagine I have a SQS queue `Q` that contains the following messages:

```
Q = [ A, B, C ]
```

I'd like to do something to `Q` so that if I try to add a new message `D` it will fail, but I can still receive messages `A`, `B`, and `C`. Again, I don't care about the order -- `C`, `A`, `B` is fine -- I just need a way to prevent new messages from being added. In this way, as long as I continue to process messages on the "closed" queue, I'm guaranteed to drain it at some point in the future.

On face, SQS doesn't seem to support that feature "out of the box." However, it looks like I can use `RemovePermission` to disallow `SendMessage` and `SendMessageBatch` on the queue for the account(s) in question.

To those who have used SQS and `RemovePermission` in the past: is this approach sane?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think you answered your own question. That's exactly what I would do. Remove the Send* permissions. There's no concept of "pausing" the queue nor is there a way to block access at the network layer. So you're stuck removing permissions. Of course any client writing to the queue will throw errors, but I assume you're planning on this.

Comment: Thank you for the validation! It's the only way I can think of to prevent submitting new messages, even though it feels a little hacky and heavy-handed.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to have some piece of configuration in your system that tells producers where to send new messages. This could allow you to "close" the old queue without messing around with permissions simply by knowing that all of your clients will follow the rules and write to the new queue.

Comment: That's a great idea! I don't control all of the producers, though, unfortunately.